# How do I input values from a list into a string?

Tags: python, string, list, format

I am trying to input the following list values into the url string below.
When I do the following:

```
tickers = ['AAPL','YHOO','TSLA','NVDA']
url = 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/{}'.format(tickers)`
```

Python returns

```
http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/['AAPL', 'YHOO', 'TSLA', 'NVDA']`
```

What I would like it to do instead is to iterate through the list and return the following:

```
http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AAPL
http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/YHOO
http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/TSLA
http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/NVDA
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A nifty trick with `map`:

```
url = 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/{}'
tickers = ['AAPL','YHOO','TSLA','NVDA']

list(map(url.format, tickers))
```

```
['http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AAPL',
 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/YHOO',
 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/TSLA',
 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/NVDA']
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
tickers = ['AAPL','YHOO','TSLA','NVDA']
url = 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/'
['{}{}'.format(url, x) for x in tickers]
```

Result is:

```
['http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AAPL',
 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/YHOO',
 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/TSLA',
 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/NVDA']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate through `tickers` with a loop, and concatenate the strings together:

```
tickers = ['AAPL','YHOO','TSLA','NVDA']
url = 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/'

for ticker in tickers:
   print(url + ticker)

# http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AAPL
# http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/YHOO
# http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/TSLA
# http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/NVDA
```

Or with a list comprehension:

```
[url + ticker for ticker in tickers]
```

Which gives the combined strings in a list:

```
['http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/AAPL', 
 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/YHOO', 
 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/TSLA', 
 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/NVDA']
```

Comment: Good old loop. Nice one. You could also add in the list comp version.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah, was about to add that. Thanks mate :).

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the list first before you pass it on. If you are trying to make one url with all the parameters into the url do this first :

```
params = "".join(tickers)
url = 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/{}'.format(params)
```

If you want multiple url's with one parameter each time do this :

```
urls = []
for param in tickers:
    urls.append('http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/{}'.format(param))
```

Comment: No, this isn't what OP asked for. They want a list of  4 separate URLs.

Answer (score 1):

you might try this:

```
tickers = ['AAPL','YHOO','TSLA','NVDA']
url = 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/'
for e in tickers:
    print(url + e)
```

this will print the urls, instead you could add them to a list aswell.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
tickers = ['AAPL','YHOO','TSLA','NVDA']
url = 'http://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/'
new_ls = (x+y for x,y in zip([url]*len(tickers),tickers))
for new_url in new_ls:
    print(new_url)
```